# Android not fetching updated JSON file

Tags: android, json

When I update the JSON file on the server, Android device is not fetching the updated file, But emulator its working fine, Emulator is fetching and displaying the updated file from the server. Is there any ways to refresh the json file through the code, and or delete the file in server cache.

AsynTask for fetching video urls from web server.

```
private class fetchVideoUrls extends AsyncTask<String, String, List<VideoModel>> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected List<VideoModel> doInBackground(String... strings) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(strings[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String resultJson = buffer.toString();
                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(resultJson);
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("videos");

                List<VideoModel> videoModelList = new ArrayList<>();

                Gson gson = new Gson();
                for (int i = 0; i < parentArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    VideoModel videoModel = gson.fromJson(finalObject.toString(), VideoModel.class);
                    videoModelList.add(videoModel);
                }
                return videoModelList;
            } catch (JSONException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<VideoModel> result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            dialog.dismiss();
            VideoAdapter adapter = new VideoAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.video_row, result);
            lvVideos.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried calling api after clearing your mobile applications cache?

Comment: @Kunu yes, I tried that, even after uninstalling the app and reinstalling on device its geting an old version of json file,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to **set cache off on HttpURLConnection before openConnection**, with method **setUseCaches**?

Method ref: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setUseCaches(boolean)

This method is inherited from URLConnection class, as explained here: http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html